# In MySQL is it possible to name a column the value of a variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, variables

I've been having trouble preparing a procedure using loops to create new columns based on the value of the variable. Whenever the procedure is run, it creates a column called "cntr," rather than the value of cntr. Here's the code:

```
BEGIN
Declare cntr INT Default 0; 
looper: LOOP
set cntr = cntr + 1;
if cntr = 334 THEN
    leave looper;
    end if;
alter table hour_time_stamp
    add column cntr int;
insert into hour_time_stamp (cntr)
        select truncate(time_stamp/3600000000000,0) from `events`
        where unit_id=cntr
        order by time_stamp DESC;
END loop looper;
END
```

Would anyone know how to name a column the value of a variable?

Comment: Save the SQL query as string, containing that variable, and then execute.

Comment: Table structure is not usually something you would create dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute dynamic sql.  Construct a string that holds the command you want plus the value of cntr then call execute on it.  Ex:

```
execute 'alter table hour_time_stamp
    add column ' + cntr + ' int';
```

To insert into the column you will have to construct your insert statement similarly.

For debugging purposes it may help to save the two sql strings into varchar variables and print those out to make sure they hold the cntr value.

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of `set`, `concat`, `prepare`, and `execute`, the column name may be substituted using a variable:

```
set @myvar ='MyColumn';
set @s = CONCAT("SELECT 'test' ", @myvar);
prepare stmt from @s;
execute stmt;
```